# setting up remote access to VPS where Wine runs; is window manager needed?

Tags: wine, window-manager, remote-access, vps

I have a VPS running Ubuntu 12.04. My purpose is to let a windows application run under Wine, around the clock, 24/7. It consists of two .exe's, both have to open their GUIs to run. From time to time I would like to have look on them, by connecting to VPS from my Windows laptop. I do not mind launching applications in Wine conncting with SSH and using command line; but I do need seeing their GUIs afterwards.

Knowing that, what do you think is an appropriate way to run Wine (using it's own window manager or Ubuntu's one) and arranging remote access (VNC? something else?)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Wine expects the DISPLAY variable to be set to a working X display. That's not a massive problem and there are a lot of solutions here.

I would personally look at starting an `Xvfb` display and then run your applications under that `DISPLAY` variable, including a VNC server.

```
sudo apt-get install xvfb wine x11vnc
Xvfb :99 &
DISPLAY=:99 wine regedit &
x11vnc -display :99 -forever
```

A few notes:

- You can tweak the `Xvfb` for geometry and colours.
- You could have a separate X/VNC server for each application.
- You can take screenshots of an X server with:

  ```
  DISPLAY=:99 import -window root screenshot.png
  ```
- For production, you'll probably want an Upstart job making sure the X server stays up. You could do the same for the Wine applications.
- None of this is secure. Don't use that in production without a firewall. I'd probably suggest limiting VNC to SSH access (tunnel the port back over SSH) if you're putting this anywhere near the internet.